Insert text between chapter and chapter title (not as an epigraph but as an entire paragraph)?
Basically I'm trying to insert text between the chapter number and it's title. Kind of like a normal paragraph but in a different place. So that the font style and size is the same as in the body of a chapter. Sort of like this:
Chapter #
normal text normal text
Chapter Title
normal text normal text
The closest to achieving what i want is doing
\chapter{}
text text text text
\section*{title}
text text text

but removing the title from the \chapter also removes it from the table of contents, but I'd like it to appear there. Also the \section* font is smaller than the chapter title size but I'd like them to be the same.
Here's all the packages I'm already using in the header.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Is this what you want?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[short title]{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\normalfont\normalsize
This will appear as normal text}\\
Long title}

Blah blah blah
\end{document}


yes, thank you! that is exactly it
